# Angular: Unclear Why Intellij Produces Unresolved Variable Warning

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem understanding why Intellij is producing an unresolved variable warning. I was hoping someone could explain why it happens.

I have an interface:

```js
export interface Foo {
    property: string;
}
```

And an observable of that type in my component:

```js
foo$: Observable<Foo>
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.foo$ = this._fooSvc.foo$;
}
```

The observable is retrieved from a service. The service declares the return type:

```js
private _fooSubject: ReplaySubject<Foo>;

get foo$(): Observable<Foo> => {
    return _fooSubject.asObservable();
}
```

And I unwrap the observable in the template using the `async` pipe, where I get the warning:

```html
[ngClass]="{my-class: (foo$ | async)?.fileName === null}"
```

So, I define a type and get an observable of that type in the component. I assign the component variable using a service method that declares a proper return type. Still get the warning.

What am I missing? Why do I get the "Unresolved variable fileName" warning in the template?

Comment: in your component, I suppose it should be  this.foo$ = this._fooSvc.foo$; instead of this.foo$ = this._fooSvc.getFoo$; ?

Comment: That's a transcription error, corrected now. Thanks for pointing that out but my question is really about IDE behavior. The actual code the samples are based on works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-45419](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45419), please follow it for updates

Answer (score 1):

It's may be because of private - make this property public.

Change:
private _fooSubject: ReplaySubject;

to:
public _fooSubject: ReplaySubject;

Or you can try File => Invalidate Cache.
But in your case I'm sure the issue is in private variable - it's not resolve to html template.